# Get button enabled inside while loop of java speech recognition sphinx API

Tags: java, swing, awt, cmusphinx

I am creating a basic Speech Recognition Java API with AWT framework.
I am done with my coding, my API too is running but now I want to introduce Stop button in my API while the recognition is going on.
I am trying to make this Stop button Enable after the start of Speech recognition.
But I am not able to do so.
I want to break the while loop of recognition on the click of Stop button and not letting while loop to infinite.
Please help me out with your suggestions..
My main class is :

```
package com.ongraph;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.TextArea;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SpeechRecognizer extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Main class of the Application. Contains the UI of Application.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Speech To Text");
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final static JPanel panel_First = new JPanel();
    final JPanel panel_Second = new JPanel();
    final JPanel panel_Third = new JPanel();
    final static TextArea textArea = new TextArea("", 10, 60);
    final JButton speak = new JButton("Speak");
    final static JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    final static JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    final BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
    final static JLabel stop_Command = new JLabel(
            "Speak 'Stop' to Stop Recording.");

    final static SpeechToTextOperation speechToTextOperation = new SpeechToTextOperation();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new SpeechRecognizer();

    }

    public SpeechRecognizer() {
        speak.setEnabled(true);
        clear.setEnabled(true);
        stop_Command.setVisible(false);
        textArea.setVisible(true);
        stop.setEnabled(false);

        // When ever Speak button is pressed this method is invoked. voiceGet()
        // method of SpeechToTextOperation class is called in this.

        speak.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                speak.setEnabled(false);
                try {
                    speechToTextOperation.voiceGet();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // When ever Clear button is pressed this methos is invoked. It clears
        // the TextArea only after the Application has been stopped.
        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                speechToTextOperation.voiceStop();
                textArea.setText("");
                speak.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        frame.add(panel_First, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel_Second, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel_Third, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_First.add(speak);
        panel_First.add(stop);
        panel_Second.add(clear);
        panel_Third.setLayout(borderLayout);
        panel_Third.add(stop_Command, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel_Third.add(textArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

The class having Sphinx code is :

```
package com.ongraph;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;

public class SpeechToTextOperation {
    ConfigurationManager cm;
    SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    Result result;
    Recognizer recognizer;
    Microphone microphone;
    private final static String STOP = "stop";
    private final static String XML_FILE = "helloworld.config.xml";

     /*Called by the click on Speak button. It recognizes your voice, matches it
     with Grammar file and displays the words spoken.*/
    public void voiceGet() throws InterruptedException {
        String resultString = null;
        int count_Check = 0;
        if (cm == null) {
            cm = new ConfigurationManager(getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResource(XML_FILE));
        }
        if (recognizer == null) {
            recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
            microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
            microphone.clear();
        }
        recognizer.allocate();
        if (!(microphone.startRecording())) {
            System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
            recognizer.deallocate();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        instructions();

        while (true) {
            System.out
                    .println("Start speaking. Speak 'Stop' to Stop Recording.");
            if (count_Check == 0) {
                SpeechRecognizer.textArea.append("\n Start speaking...\n");
                count_Check++;
            }
            SpeechRecognizer.stop.setEnabled(true);
            Result result = recognizer.recognize();
            resultString = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
            if (!resultString.contains(STOP)) {
                SpeechRecognizer.textArea.append(resultString + "\n");
            } else {
                SpeechRecognizer.textArea
                        .append("'Application Stopped. Press 'Speak' again to restart'");
                recognizer.deallocate();
                microphone.stopRecording();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

     /*Clears the Microphone so that new words can be recognized and frees the
     ConfigurationManager Object.*/
    public void voiceStop() {
        microphone.clear();
        cm = null;
    }

    // Provides you instruction how to stop the Application
    public void instructions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SpeechRecognizer.stop_Command.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `public static boolean isStart;` in your main and reference it for your while loop.

So instead of using `while(true)` you can use something like `while(main.isStart)`.
Then just set `isStart = false;` when the stop button is press, and set `isStart = true;` then when start button is press.

You should always avoid using `while(true)` in your code, there is most likely a better way of going about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But actually the issue is, as soon as I click on 'Speak' button my API UI gets hanged. I am not able to press any button neither any button responds until and unless I comes out from this while loop.

Comment: If your UI is stopping for the speaking process, you might want to have it run on a separate thread and run asyncronously. Look over http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for using Async tasks.